# Select an element in parent Window from Iframe in an onclick event Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, jquery-selectors

Take a look at this code in the Iframe:

```
$(document).on('click', "#elementfromparentwindow",function (e) {

});
```

How do I select the element from parent Window in an on click event in the Iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be done through window.parent, like below:

```
    var parentItem = window.parent.document.getElementById('elementfromparentwindow'); 

    $(parentItem).on('click', function(){

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Got it working a few moments ago..

```
$("#elementfromparentwindow",window.parent.document).on('click',function (e) {

});
```